# Python Bar string on x axis

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, axis

I have 2 arrays like below:

```
x = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November',
 'December']
y = [5.3, 6.1, 25.5, 27.8, 31.2, 33.0, 33.0, 32.8, 28.4, 21.1, 17.5, 11.9]
```

and i need to put the months on x axis and max temperatures for months on y axis. However, when I use the code below:

```
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

    x = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November',
         'December']
    y = [5.3, 6.1, 25.5, 27.8, 31.2, 33.0, 33.0, 32.8, 28.4, 21.1, 17.5, 11.9]

    plt.bar(x, y, color='green',align='center')
    plt.title('Max Temperature for Monthes')
    plt.legend()
    plt.show()
```

I get this value error: ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'January'

How can i solve this? How can i put string values on x axis?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Matplotlib has an [example](http://matplotlib.org/examples/api/barchart_demo.html) that accomplishes what you're trying to do.

To create a plot, you have to have numerical data for both dimensions as otherwise, `matplotlib` doesn't know what to do. Instead, you have to add the strings as labels to your ticks:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = range(12)
x_labels = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November',
     'December']
y = [5.3, 6.1, 25.5, 27.8, 31.2, 33.0, 33.0, 32.8, 28.4, 21.1, 17.5, 11.9]

plt.bar(x, y, color='green', align='center')
plt.title('Max Temperature for Monthes')
plt.xticks(x, x_labels, rotation='vertical')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank u very much, could u please give me a hint how can i position the monthes exactly on green bars adn rotate them 45 degrees left please?

Comment: Use `plt.xticks(rotation=45)`. Added to my answer too.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `plt.xticks` as documented [here](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.xticks)

Here's how to use it with your code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

months = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December']
monthsRange = np.arange(len(months))
temperatures = [5.3, 6.1, 25.5, 27.8, 31.2, 33.0, 33.0, 32.8, 28.4, 21.1, 17.5, 11.9]

plt.bar(monthsRange, temperatures, color='green')
plt.title('Max Temperature for Monthes')
plt.xticks(monthsRange, months)
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
plt.bar(range(len(x)), y, color='green',align='center')
plt.xticks(range(len(x)), x)
plt.xticks(rotation=45)
```

Use xticks. Refer [this](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.xticks)

Answer (score 1):

You need to represent the labels as numbers then set the labels separately. Finally, you need to rotate the labels otherwise they will all be stacked on top of one another.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np



labels = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November',
     'December']

x = list(range(12))
y = [5.3, 6.1, 25.5, 27.8, 31.2, 33.0, 33.0, 32.8, 28.4, 21.1, 17.5, 11.9]

plt.bar(x, y, color='green',align='center')
plt.title('Max Temperature for Monthes')
plt.xticks(x, labels)
plt.xticks(rotation=70)
plt.legend()


plt.show()
```

Comment: i am very grateful. that was exactly what i wanted,

Comment: just in different version of that that i get TypeError: unorderable types: str() < int() this error. do u have any idea why?